# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal (keras)

Tags: python-3.x, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to train an autoencoder but have problems in reshaping my X_train to fit it to my model model().

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

from keras.utils import plot_model

X_train = np.array(X_train, dtype=np.float)
X_test =np.array(X_train, dtype=np.float)

X_train = X_train.reshape(len(X_train), 100,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(len(X_test), 100,1)

#inputs = Input(shape=(230, 1,100))
epoch = 100
batch = 128

def model():
    m = Sequential()
    # ##m.add(Reshape((,)))
    m.add(Flatten())
    m.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    m.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(Dense(2, activation = 'linear'))
    m.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
    m.add(Dense(784, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    
    m.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    # Fit data to model m
    m.fit(X_train, X_train, batch_size = batch, epochs = epoch)
    m.summary()
    
    #score = m.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose = 0)
    #print('Test loss:' score[0])
    #print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    #m.summary()
    
    
mod = model()
```

The of dimension of my data is the following:

X_train = (523, 100,1)
X_test = (523, 100,1)

Comment: the last dimension when u operate data reshape seems to be useless... 784 in the network output is different from the output dimension

Comment: Since you are training your model with X_train, X_train the output of your model must have the same dimension as X_train (i.e., (batch_size, 100, 1). Try to change m.add(Dense(784, activation = 'sigmoid')) to m.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid')). You can check the expected input/output shapes of your model with model.input_shape or model.output_shape (and also with model.summary()).

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right. I wasn't paying attention. However when I change to 100 I get the following error:  Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 100 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,100].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue, change the following:

```py
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, 100))
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 100))
```

Delete the `Flatten` layer and use `100` neurons for the last layer as stated in the comments.